# Chart With Multiple BackColours c#

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I'm looking to fill a c# chart with multiple backcolours in relation to timestamp.

Does anyone know of any code to do this or perhaps a method to implement the equivalent.

I thought about adding semi-transparent columns with appropriate widths but this seems a bit messy.

Any insight and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: show your tried code.

Comment: This sound like a jobe for [StripLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958646/winforms-chart-how-to-enable-background-color-gauge/38959173#38959173)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `mschart`

1. Use a timer
2. Every tick event, set `back color` to `color you want`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but will that change the entire background colour of the chart per tick or will it colour it in periods so you get a progressive colour change?

Comment: yes, it will change the whole background color every tick.

Comment: sorry, to be more specific the application requires a progressive of colour with time thus when viewing historic data a chart will appear to have a different colour depending on time of day. It's to represent RAG times used in power distribution

Comment: It would be helpful if you can picture your idea inside your question to help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you

> ```
>        foreach (Series charts in chart1.Series)
>         {
>             foreach (DataPoint point in charts.Points)
>             {
>                 if (point.AxisLabel == LibereStr)
>                 {
>                     point.Color = Color.Green;
>                     point.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
>                     if (Libere == 0)
>                     {
>                         point.IsEmpty = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else if (point.AxisLabel == OccupateStr)
>                 {
>                     point.Color = Color.Red;
>                     point.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
>                     if (Occupate == 0)
>                     {
>                         point.IsEmpty = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else if (point.AxisLabel == PrenotateStr)
>                 {
>                     point.Color = Color.Violet;
>                     point.Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
>                     if (Prenotate == 0)
>                     {
>                         point.IsEmpty = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 point.Label = string.Format("{0:0} - {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel);
>             }
>         }
> ```